# How to change the default locale in GXT?

Tags: gxt

I don't need the default english locale, only pt_BR. If I do this:

```
<extend-property name="locale" values="pt_BR"/>
```

...it will generate one permutation for english (which is the default locale) and another one for pt_BR. How can I avoid the default english one?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add two lines

```
<extend-property name="locale" values="pt_BR" />
<set-property-fallback name="locale" value="pt_BR" />
<set-property name="locale" value="pt_BR" />
```